# PayPal Express Checkout - PayPal button not getting rendered on iOS

Tags: ios, cordova, hybrid-mobile-app, paypal

I am building a hybrid application using cordova. Also I am using Express checkout to integrate PayPal with the application referring [this](https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/client) example

This code is working well on Android but not working on iPhone. The PayPal button is not getting rendered.

Is there any other way to integrate PayPal in hybrid apps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More than likely it's the external javascript that's causing you an issue.  Check for XSS permissions to load them.  Also ensure that javascript is enabled for your web view.

You can also debug a Cordova application (or any web view in iOS) using the developer menu in Safari and see any Javascript or XSS errors in that layer.

Comment: I would give you a vote for XSS check; as cordova whitelist plugin was blocking paypal iframe to render on the webview. Thanks for suggestion!!